# "Upgraded" Quadratic Equation

Tags: linear-algebra

$x^2-15x+36=0$ is a simple quadratic equation, and it is clear that the sum of roots is $15$.

However, I thought this could be made harder so I put the QE as something like this:

> Find sum of roots of the equation $$x^2-15\lfloor x\rfloor+36=0$$

Clearly, 3 and 12 can solve this equation. However, how should I find the sum of all possible real $x$ which solve the equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:
$$x^2+36=15\lfloor  x\rfloor$$
If $x>12$ then $x^2+36>15x$ also if $x<3$ then $15\lfloor x\rfloor<36$.

Now take $\lfloor x\rfloor=3,4,5,\cdots,12$ for each you will find an unique solution.If the solution fits the required interval for floor then it is the solution.

Comment: Sorry, still can't, may I ask for more help?

Comment: @MathEnthusiast Sure, my hint was kinda off edited.

Comment: There are 6 solutions.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Thanks,you're right my mistake.